# Why does command window say "use of \end does not match definition"?

Tags: errors

Having  successfully compiled about 200 files for my website 
[www.earlymoderntexts.com](http://www.earlymoderntexts.com/), I have run into four that won't compile, and I can't find out why. With each of them, the command window's complaints start with "use of `\end` doesn't match its definition", and I am bewildered by this; I can't find anything unusual in the use of `\end` in these files. Can someone help me? A plea from an 87-year-old retired philosophy professor!

Comment: Without seeing some code, there is not much that can be said.

Comment: you have something that has redefined `\end`   add `\show\end` to your document then tex will stop and show the definition, as if for an error message. add the message from the log file to your question and someone can help...

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1436/welcome-to-tex-sx)

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX!! Can you please try and cut down one of your files to a [minimal working example](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/228). A MWE should start with a `\documentclass` command, have a minimal preamble  and then `\begin{document}...\end{document}`. The code should be as small as possible to demonstrate your problem. If you start with one of the problematic files, make a copy, and then keep deleting things until the problem goes away. This way you can home in on the real problem and produce a MWE and some one might be able to help.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle That being the case, I deleted my comments, so as to not distract from the question.

Answer (score 2):

You should not look at the use of `\end` within the document but at a (probably accidental) redefinition of it, perhaps in the preamble.

For example this document produces the error shown

```
\documentclass{article}

\def\end oops{}

\begin{document}


\begin{quote}
  zzzz
\end{quote}
\end{document}
```

with error:

```
! Use of \end doesn't match its definition.
l.10 \end{
          quote}
?
```

The use of \end `\end{quote}` and `\end{document}` look OK but `\end` has been redefined in a way that it must always be followed by `oops`.

To see this (assuming the redefinition is in some package code) modify the docuemnt as follows:

```
\show\end

\documentclass{article}

\show\end

\def\end oops{}

\show\end

\begin{document}


\begin{quote}
  zzzz
\end{quote}
\end{document}
```

Now the log shows:

```
LaTeX2e <2017-04-15>
Babel <3.14> and hyphenation patterns for 84 language(s) loaded.
> \end=macro:
#1->\csname end#1\endcsname \@checkend {#1}\expandafter \endgroup \if@endpe \@d
oendpe \fi \if@ignore \@ignorefalse \ignorespaces \fi .
l.2 \show\end

? 
(/usr/local/texlive/2017/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/article.cls
Document Class: article 2014/09/29 v1.4h Standard LaTeX document class
(/usr/local/texlive/2017/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/size10.clo))
> \end=macro:
#1->\csname end#1\endcsname \@checkend {#1}\expandafter \endgroup \if@endpe \@d
oendpe \fi \if@ignore \@ignorefalse \ignorespaces \fi .
l.6 \show\end

? 
> \end=macro:
oops->.
l.10 \show\end

? 

! Use of \end doesn't match its definition.
l.17 \end{
          quote}
?
```

Which tells you that `\end` had its normal definition on lines 2 and 6 but on line 10 it had a changed definition.

By  adding a few `\show\end` in your document you should be able to find at what point `\end` got changed.